# How can I create Android App with existing code?

Tags: android, android-keystore

I developed an Android app and published it on google play. Then I lost my keystore file and now I can't update my app. Therefore, I want to create new app with my existing code.

How can I use my existing code to create the new application, porting clearly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is change the package declarations in the Manifest and in each source file.  Once it's in a different package the Google Play Store will think it's a different application and you can upload the new build.

Comment: Only these change is enough ?

Comment: Yes, this is how the store tells the apps apart and this will make it look like a completely different app.

Comment: Ok I change all of them but [ProjectName]>[src]>com.example.blabla doesnt change ? Is it a problem ?

Comment: Yes, you need to change the package name everywhere.